# Do all C++ operators take operands?

Tags: c++, operators

All C++ operators that I have worked with takes operands, for example the `+` operator takes two operands.

Do all C++ operators take operands, or are there some C++ operators that do not take any operand?

Comment: There's a nullary version of `throw`, but it could be debated whether that's still an operator.

Answer (score 4):

`throw` in its nullary form is the only operator that doesn't take an argument. Consider:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

void foo()
{
    try {
        std::srand(std::time(0));
        throw rand() % 2;
    } catch (int n){
        std::cout << "foo " << (n ? n : throw);
    }
}

int main()
{
    try {
        foo();
    } catch (int n){
        std::cout << "main " << n;
    }
}
```

where `throw` (which in its *nullary* form throws the current exception *by reference*) is clearly an operator since it can be written within the ternary conditional operator. `foo` will throw an exception approximately 50% of the time, with the output in either case yielding a primitive sort of stack trace.

`noexcept` without an operand is not an *operator* but a *specifier*, so that doesn't count.